# Что за конструкиця в php

Tags: php

```
function TypeInterface::validate($aValue): bool;
```

более 6 лет работаю на php, и в первый раз увидел такую конструкцию в примерах кода на habr.

Кто-то сталкивался? Что вообще происходит и что это `::` в контексте объявлении прототипа метода ?

Comment: Это наверное не должно работать..

Comment: @InDevX где? По ссылке ничего похожего не нашел. Только это - `ClassName::methodName' доступна как функция-переменная.` ни примеров, ни описания нет..

Comment: Не о том подумал. Можете ссылкой поделиться где встречали?

Comment: Предполагаю что речь об этой статье https://m.habr.com/ru/post/331160/ и использовании валидаторов для обработки входящих данных

Comment: Это просто описание, точнее ссылка на метод класса, а не декларирование функции. Такой же подход применяется в phpDoc например. Чтобы сослаться на метод какого-то класса пишут это через `::`. Иначе было глупо ссылаться на какой-то метод видом `(new MyClass)->method()` пример из phpdoc https://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/tags/see.html